# Calculating Duration of AB test for measuring sales change in stores

Tags: statistical-significance, inference, standard-deviation, sample-size, ab-test

I have done my research about AB testing an seen that it is usually implemented in the online space(websites etc), I am trying to implement the same concept but at a store level.

Problem: Given a list of stores, find the number of transactions required and the duration for which the AB test should run, to get a statistically significant sales lift(in my case 4%).

Online scenario : Now what I have seen is that for the online scenario, the sample size is calculated using the number of users that should visit a certain website for the results to be statistically significant. Once you have the number of users, you can extrapolate and come up with the approximate number of days required (based on how many users visit everyday).

Offline scenario: In my case I am not sure as to if i should take transaction as a proxy for user or should I use sales per store or sales per transaction and then calculate the standard deviation & mean of the proposed metric ,which can then allow me to use a 2 sample Z-test to calculate the sample size i.e. in my case the number of transactions required for a 5% change in sales.

Looking forward to some inputs.

Answer (score 0):

This is a tough problem mostly because you have no way to identify customers.  You would have to make some very strong assumptions about who comes into the store and when in order to perform the inference.  For example, suppose you run a hardware store.  How would you distinguish actual improvement in sales vs. one contractor coming in and buying his/her materials over the course of a week just by looking at sales data?  It would be hard.

Those problems aside, you have to ask what you want to know.  Are you interested in increasing total sales, or average basket?  Basket is easier to analyze since you are looking at transaction level data, where as total sales would likely require some sort of difference in difference design in which you need data from several months/weeks (depending on the time frame).

So I guess this is a question back to you:  What specifically do you want to test?  Avg basket, total sales per month, etc.  What are you trying to improve?

Comment: I agree that a lot of assumptions have to be made but lets say for now I am trying to test the hypothesis that a particular pricing change for some items in the test store will drive more sales as compared to the control stores.

Comment: @bakas So the metric here is number of sales per store?  Do you have an intended timeframe, like sales per store per week?

Comment: Yeah I am aggregating data at Store week level(Sales), but I am just trying to understand is that the right metric, given that finally I need to calculate the number of transactions(synonymous to number of user in online sense) required to statistically validate that their is a lift between test & control stores.